# Proble in debuging c++ code with visual studio code, with lunch.json file

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have Problem in debugging c++ programs in **Visual studio code**. Although, debugging was working before. I had not change any configuration or setting. When i opened **visual studio code** today then i saw that error. 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vVLj.png)

***lunch.json***

```js
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have not changed anything in system/vc code/ configuration etc.
Then, why debugging stops working.

Comment: Is the executable file created successfully? The error says it doesn't exist, so you should make sure it has really been created

Comment: Yes, executable file is created successfully. It is running and producing output. There is no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program setting specifies the program you want to debug. Here it is set to the active file folder **${fileDirname}** and active filename with the .exe extension **${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe**, which if helloworld.cpp is the active file will be helloworld.exe.

 The main problem is vccode is not able to find the current file for debugging. 
These are some links that might work for you.

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugging-a-stack-overflow)

[Configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference)